# Cannot POST/update/ "while updating the user details"

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

"cannot post/update/" I am facing the error while updating the details of the user

Everything is running fine from signUp to signIn and displaying the details and deleting it but when I try to update it says "Cannot post/update/"

Node js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const app = express()

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    mobile: Number,
    email: String,
    password: String
})

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)

//to store data into database...
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    var name = req.body.Fname
    var email = req.body.email
    var mobile = req.body.mobile
    var password = req.body.password

    var data = new User({
        'name' : name,
        'email': email,
        'mobile': mobile,
        'password': password
    })

    data.save()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('user saved to database')
            res.redirect('/signIn.html')
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error')
        })
})

//to display starting page (signup page)
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

//to display the user details...
app.post('/login', async(req, res) => {
   try {
        const email = req.body.email
        const password = req.body.password

        const userDetails = await User.findOne({email: email})
        if(userDetails.password === password) {
            res.render('user', {user: userDetails})
        }
        else {
            res.send('Invalid Password')
        }
   }
   catch(err) {
        res.send('Invalid UserID')
   }
})

//for deleting the user...
app.post('/delete/:id', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const id = req.params.id
        await User.deleteOne({_id : id})
        res.redirect('/');
    }
    catch(err) {
        res.send('Error while Deleting')
    }
})

//for editing the user details...
app.get('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const id = req.params.id
        const user = User.findOne(id)
        
        res.render('update', {user: user})
    }
    catch(err) {
        res.send('Error while editing')
    }
})

//Facing an error while calling the update "cannot post/update/"

app.post('/update/:id', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const id = req.body.id

        const newData = {
            name : req.body.Fname,
            email : req.body.email,
            mobile : req.body.mobile,
            password : req.body.password
        }

        await User.findOneAndUpdate({id : id}, newData)
        
        res.redirect('/signIn.html')
    }
    catch(err) {
        res.send('Error while updating')
    }
})

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('server is running');
})

console.log("Everything runs perfect")
```

Html for signUp

```
<form action="/Signup" id="container" method="post">
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="Fname" required>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Mobile" name="mobile" required>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
    <input type="Password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="Cpassword" required>
    <input type="submit" value="sign up" class="btn">
</form>
```

Html for signIn

```
<form action="/login" id="container" method="post">
    <h1>Sign IN</h1>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">
    <input type="Password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="sign up" class="btn">
</form>
```

EJS for displaying user details

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>User Details</h1>
    <div>
        <h2>Username: <%= user.name %></h2>
        <h3>Email: <%= user.email %></h3>
        <h3>Mobile: <%= user.mobile %></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="btns">
        <form action="/edit/<%= user._id%>" method="get">
            <input type="submit" value="Edit">
        </form>
        <form action="/delete/<%= user._id%>" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="deleteBtn">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

EJS for updating user details

```
<form action="/update/<%= user._id%>" id="container" method="post">
    <h1>Update</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="Fname">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Mobile" name="mobile">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" class="btn">Update</input>
</form>
```

Comment: it should be `const id = req.params.id` instead of `const id = req.body.id`. And you should send the id in the url like `.../update/123`